# What is the most appropriate method to recover words transcription from the phoneme sequence with errors?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I conduct some experiments on continuous speech recognition. After the initial application of the recognizer I have the phoneme sequence that includes some errors (three types of errors: substitution, deletion and inclusion). For instance:
I obtain

*h e l' l o n y k f r a n d s t*

instead of

*h e l l o m y f r i e n d s*

So, the task is use the information about language (correct transcription of every word, valid word order etc.) in order to recover the correct transcription from the phoneme sequence corrupted by noise.

I wondered about Hidden Markov Models, but I am not shore how to use it here.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using weighted finite state transducers. First create character to word transducer L. Then create a weighted edit transducer E to assign penalties to the error tyopes. Represent your input as automata and then compose each of the machines and find the lowest cost path through the resulting machine. The following website should be of help
http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata